# Что не так с перцептроном?

Tags: c#, нейронные-сети

Пишу простой линейный перцептрон с обучением с учителем. Нужно по координатам точки в пространстве определить, к какому октанту она относится.
Вроде бы всё сделал по инструкции:

```
class Program
{
    private static void Teach(double[] x, double[,] w, double alpha, double theta, int octant)
    {
        double[] net = new double[8];
        double[] o = new double[8];
        double[] target = new double[8];
        double[] error = new double[8];
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            net[j] = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                net[j] += x[i] * w[i, j];
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) 
        { 
            if (net[j] > theta) o[j] = 1;
            else o[j] = 0;
            if (j == octant - 1) target[j] = 1;
            else target[j] = 0;
            error[j] = target[j] - o[j];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                w[i, j] += alpha * x[i] * error[j];
            }
        }
    }
    static int Recognize (double[] x, double[,] w, double theta)
    {
        int res = -1;
        double max = -999;
        double[] net = new double[8];
        double[] o = new double[8];
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            net[j] = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                net[j] += x[i] * w[i, j];
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        { 
            if (net[j] > max)
            {
                max = net[j];
                res = j + 1;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n, octant;
        double[] x = new double[3];
        double[,] w = new double[3, 8]; //веса
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) w[i, j] = 0.1;
        double alpha = 1; //скорость обучения
        double theta = 0; //общий порог для всех нейронов
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("teach.txt");
        foreach (string s in lines)
        {
            string[] nums = s.Split(' ');
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) x[i] = Convert.ToDouble(nums[i]);
            octant = Convert.ToInt32(nums[3]);
            Teach(x, w, alpha, theta, octant);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Обучение завершено");
        Console.WriteLine("Введите строку для распознавания");
        lines = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            x[i] = Convert.ToDouble(lines[i]);
        }
        int r = Recognize(x, w, theta);
        Console.WriteLine("Октант: " + r);
        }
    }
```

Файл teach.txt: [здесь](https://pastebin.com/gt51WnQC)

Однако всё распознаётся неправильно: все точки определяются не тем октантом. В чём ошибка и что нужно поменять?

Upd: попробовал выставить веса согласно знакам октантов,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) w[i, j] = 0.1 * sgn[j, i];
```

а при расчёте выхода нейрона использовал модуль координаты

```
for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            net[j] = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                net[j] += Math.Abs(x[i]) * w[i, j];
            }
        }
```

-и всё заработало!

Из-за чего это может происходить?